# Flask: render_template with object passing says "method not allowed"

Tags: redirect, flask

I have a dynamic table with students based on class block. That is the table has the list of students in each period block. The HTML which dynamically builds this is

```
    html += "<tr>"+
        "<td class='align-middle'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check' style='width:50px;height:50px;'></td>"+
        "<td class='align-middle'><input type='image' onclick='StudentClicked(\""+item.FirstName+"\",\""+item.LastName+"\",\""+item.Suffix+"\",\""+item.NickName+"\")' src="+path+" onError='StudentImageError("+i+")' id='studentimage"+i+"' height='100'></td>"+
        "<td class='align-middle'>"+item.FirstName +" "+item.LastName+"</td>"+
        "<td class='align-middle'></td>"+
        "<td class='align-middle'>0</td>" +
        "<td class='align-middle'>0</td>"+
        "</tr>"
```

Therefore when the user clicks the image, StudentClicked is called.

```
    function StudentClicked(FirstName, LastName, Suffix, NickName){
        $.getJSON('/studentSelected', 
                {firstName: FirstName, lastName: LastName, suffix: Suffix, nickName: NickName},
                function(data){})
    }
```

The idea here is that I want to click the image link and the getJSON will look for my app.route("/studentSelected"). I will perform a database call with the variables I have passed to this route and build an object. I want to pass this object to an html page. Here is the python code for the app.route

```
@app.route('/studentSelected', methods=['GET','POST'])
def studentSelected():
    firstName = request.args.get('firstName', 0, type=str)
    lastName = request.args.get('lastName', 0, type=str)
    suffix = request.args.get('suffix', 0, type=str)
    nickName = request.args.get('nickName', 0, type=str)
    students = []    
    con, cur = ConnectToDatabase()

    SQL = "select * from students where FirstName = ? and LastName = ? and Suffix = ? and NickName = ?"
    entities = (firstName, lastName, suffix, nickName)
    student, cur = Execute(SQL, cur, entities)

    return render_template('studentcard.html', student=student)
```

Currently I get "Method Not Allowed. The method is not allowed for the requested URL." which I interpret as I'm not passing the right method to my route. But as you can I do pass both methods to my route. Why else would I be getting this error? studentcard.html exists in the folder templates.

One guess I have is that the return statement returns functionality to the getJSON function.

What is a better strategy for this type of process. The end result is for the clicked image to run app.route, call the database and then redirect the webapp to a new route for studentSelected and load and run this page.

contents of studentcard.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container mt-3">
{% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}


</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: could you plz share the traceback

Comment: In running a traceback I get the following error. TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Comment: @DaveK Could you paste `studentcard.html` contents? Which view renders the table you pasted?

Comment: I have added this to the original post. Also I am continuing to try and solve it and I now have for my function(data){window.location.href = "/studentCard";} This does send control back to my app.route("/studentCard") but I do not know how to the append my object 'data' to this. I'm so close yet so far. the object Data does in fact contain all information I need to send to the app.route function.